# Mutate a column as the weighted mean of selected columns, with indexed weights in another tibble

Tags: r, tidyverse

```
db = tibble(a = rnorm(1000),
            b = rnorm(1000),
            c = rnorm(1000))

w = tibble(col = c("a","b","c"),
           w = c(.4,.4,.2))
```

I want to mutate a column `AVG` in `db` which is the weighted average of a selection of `db`, for simplicity `is.numeric`, looking for weights in `w`.

I want it scalable for any selection, i.e. an `across()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

```
db |>
  rowid_to_column() |>
  pivot_longer(-rowid, names_to = "col") |> # here's where one could specify cols
  left_join(w) |>
  summarize(AVG = sum(value * w), .by = rowid)
```

Or wrap in `db |> bind_cols( ... )` to attach to the original data.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
db$AVG <- c(crossprod(t(db), with(w, w[match(col, names(db))])))
```

or simply with `rowSums`

```
db$AVG <- with(w, rowSums(db * w[match(col, names(db))][col(db)]))
```

Comment: I don't think this equates, in the specific example, with 

  (db[1] * w$w[1]) +
  (db[2] * w$w[2]) +
  (db[3] * w$w[3])